# Backpreesing takes me to previous activity

Tags: android, facebook-login, account-kit

I know this question has been asked many times but hear me out. I have MainActivity which is a LoginActivity & it uses facebook login and AccountKit From Facebook to login and start next activity which is a ContactsActivity. When i am in ContactsActivity and  press back button it takes me to MainActivity but i want to close the application as user has successfully logined in and if the user again opens the app it should open ContactsActivity directly as user has signed in successfully previously.

Problem is when i press Back button in Contacts Activity,it takes me to LoginActivity,i already tried finish() after startActivity(intent) which closes my app and not takes me to ContactsActivity after successfull signin.If i open my app again then it takes me directly to ContactsActivity.
I even tried onBackPressed in which i wrote finish but it doesnt work.
In Android Manifest also i wrote android:noHistory="true" in MainActivity tag but it doesn't work.
Please help

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="pritish.sawant.com.simplychat.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginwithphonenumber"
        android:text="@string/loginwithphoneno"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email_login_button"
        android:text="@string/loginwithemail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginwithphonenumber"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/email_login_button"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"

        />





</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static int APP_REQUEST_CODE=1;
    private LoginButton facebookloginButton;
    private Button emailloginbutton,phonenologinbutton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        facebookloginButton=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
        emailloginbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.email_login_button);
        phonenologinbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginwithphonenumber);

        callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        facebookloginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                launchContactsActivity();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.loginfailed,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        AccessToken accessToken= AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken();
        com.facebook.AccessToken loginToken= com.facebook.AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if(accessToken!=null || loginToken!=null){
            launchContactsActivity();
        }


        emailloginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onLogin(LoginType.EMAIL);

            }
        });

        phonenologinbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onLogin(LoginType.PHONE);

            }
        });

    }

    private void launchContactsActivity(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ContactsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    private void onLogin(final LoginType loginType) {
        // create intent for the Account Kit activity
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountKitActivity.class);

        // configure login type and response type
        AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
                new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                        loginType,
                        AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN
                );
        final AccountKitConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

        // launch the Account Kit activity
        intent.putExtra(AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION, configuration);
        startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(requestCode==APP_REQUEST_CODE){
            AccountKitLoginResult accountKitLoginResult=data.getParcelableExtra(AccountKitLoginResult.RESULT_KEY);
            if(accountKitLoginResult.getError()!=null){
                String toastMessage = accountKitLoginResult.getError().getErrorType().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (accountKitLoginResult.getAccessToken() != null) {
                launchContactsActivity();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add the code which you tried so far.

Comment: Please have a look,i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

In normal way you shouldn't close app - user will moves it to back by pressing home or closing your activities by pressing back.

But you can use this tips:

1) Close old activities after starting the new ones if they not needed in back stack:

```
startActivity(newActivityIntent);
finish();
```

The override onBackPressed and the app will close

2) You can move task to back (instead of close) if you need http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean)

Comment: Getting an error at LoginActivity.super.onBackPressed();

Comment: if i use finish() instead of going to contactsactivity,it closes my app